# Shrinking the window size as expander closes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window-resize, expander

Hey guys I have 3 column expanders, when you have them all open and resize the window they stretch properly to fit the window. When you an close expander, I want it to shrink the window by the width of that expander when it was open. It currently closes the expander back down to 20pixels but the open expanders will be larger (it stretches to fill in the empty space).

Code:

```
<UserControls:ExpanderWindow x:Class="Lainezor.Windows.ExpanderWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:xt="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit.Extended"
    xmlns:pg="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.PropertyGrid;assembly=WPFToolkit.Extended"
    xmlns:MyUserControls="clr-namespace:Lainezor.UserControls.ExpanderControls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" Background="AliceBlue" 
    ResizeMode="CanResize" WindowStartupLocation="Manual" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ColumnDefinition">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="20" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=Expander1}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="20*" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ColumnDefinition.Style>
        </ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
        <ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ColumnDefinition">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="20" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=Expander2}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="20*" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ColumnDefinition.Style>
        </ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
        <ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ColumnDefinition">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="20" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=Expander3}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="20*" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ColumnDefinition.Style>
        </ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Expander Name="Expander1" Grid.Column="0" IsExpanded="True" IsEnabled="True" ExpandDirection="Right">
        <Expander.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceWrapper}, Path=MyStrings.Expander1Label}"  RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" >
                <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
            </TextBlock>
        </Expander.Header>
        <MyUserControls:UserControl1 x:Name="UserControl1" SizeChanged="UserControl1_SizeChanged"/>
    </Expander>
    <GridSplitter x:Name="gridSplitter" Grid.Column="1" Width="2" Background="#CBE5FE" ResizeDirection="Columns" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Expander Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Name="Expander2" ExpandDirection="Right" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Expander.Header >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceWrapper}, Path=MyStrings.Expander2Label}">
                <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="90" />              
                </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
            </TextBlock>
        </Expander.Header>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <MyUserControls:UserControl2 x:Name="UserControl2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </Grid>
    </Expander>
    <GridSplitter x:Name="gridSplitterTwo" Grid.Column="3" Width="2" Background="#CBE5FE" ResizeDirection="Columns" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Expander Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="2" Name="Expander3" ExpandDirection="Right">
        <Expander.Header >
            <TextBlock Text="Lainezor">
                <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="90" />              
                </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
            </TextBlock>
        </Expander.Header>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <MyUserControls:UserControl3 x:Name="UserControl3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </Grid>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Have you set the `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` for the Window?

Comment: Yes it is set to WidthAndHeight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach an event handler to the collapsed event of the expander and subtract the `((Expander)sender).ActualWidth -20` from the window width

Answer (score 11):

Set the `SizeToContent` of the Window to `"WidthAndHeight"` and do not set it's `Width` or `Height` or designWidth or designHeight.

Comment: The 1st expander is expanded when the window is opened and the usercontrol inside it has a width of 300. This I cannot alter.

Comment: I think it would be better if you post the complete xaml code of the Window.